# go heroku web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: go, heroku

even i set port number from .env file i still facing  `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` error.

Here is logs:

```
2020-10-21T21:38:27.014447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-sierra-11233.herokuapp.com request_id=229ae08d-617b-4432-a738-21cce76c4e6a fwd="78.183.88.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

in main.go:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()

port := os.Getenv("db_port")
if port == "" {
    port = "8000"
}
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You have to bind to the port specified by the `PORT` env var, not `db_port`. So use `port := os.Getenv("PORT")`.

Comment: @icza that's solved! if you post it as answer then i will be accept it.

Comment: The exact answer is in the marked duplicate.